# Crawling Depth with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rcrawler

Is there a function within the beautifulsoup package that allows users to set crawling depth within a site? I am relatively new to Python but I have used Rcrawler in R before and Rcrawler provides 'MaxDepth' so the crawler will go within a certain number of links from the homepage within that domain.

```
Rcrawler(Website = "https://stackoverflow.com/", no_cores = 4, no_conn = 4, ExtractCSSPat = c("div"), ****MaxDepth=5****)
```

The basics of my current script in Python parses all visible text on a page but I would like to set a crawling depth.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    elif isinstance(element,bs.element.Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

html = urllib.request.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/').read()
print(text_from_html(html))
```

Any insight or direction is appreciated.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is for parsing, not crawling. I believe [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) can be a good fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function in `BeautifulSoup` because `BeautifulSoup` is not `crawler`.
It only parses string with `HTML` so you could search in `HTML`.

There is no function in `requests` because `requests` is no `crawler` too.
It only reads data from server so you could use it with `BeautifulSoup` or similar.

If you use `BeautifulSoup` and `request` then you have to do all on your own - you have to build crawling system from scratch.

[Scrapy](https://scrapy.org) is real crawler (or rather framework to build spiders and crawl network).
And it has option [DEPTH_LIMIT](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit)